# Application design using Netty

Tags: netty

I am looking for some theoretical advice on implementing a quiz server using Netty. The three major requirements of the server would be:

- The server is authoritative and controls the progression of the quiz. For example, users register to take part in the quiz (like room/lobby). Once ready, the server progresses through the questions and moves on to the next after a certain period of time has elapsed or when everyone answers.
- The user has ten seconds to answer the question. The amount of time they take to answer the question and the amount of time they have remaining is important to the quiz. The users participating in the quiz would be geographically diverse (i.e. over WAN links).
- It has to be scalable e.g. a quiz might have ten questions and thirty users while the next might have one hundred questions and ten thousand users.

Would Netty be a suitable solution for this? Are there any good books on Netty? I couldn't see any Kindle books on Amazon. Can anyone offer any advice or samples regarding the second point (specifically a time-critical client/server example that takes latency/transmission time in to account)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't know any books about netty, but the online documentation together with JavaDocs and examples are pretty good. Here is a handful of examples:

- if you want to serve thousands of concurrent users/connections, non-blocking I/O is your only choice. Java (and OS) won't handle thousands of threads effectively, needed for blocking I/O. netty can, without creating that many threads.
- netty is as good as underlying protocol (TCP/IP or UDP). You cannot work around network latency. E.g. sending a packet from USA to Europe will take around 150 ms.
- if timing is so important, you might need to synchronize the clocks somehow or use central time source. Check out [ntp](/questions/tagged/ntp)
- you must decide how your protocol will interact with the server:

  - short request/response connections, established every time users wants to upload question or get new one - think [http](/questions/tagged/http). This will be very slow, but quite reliable (you don't have to worry about long-lasting connections being interrupted
  - establishing one connection per user, lasting throughout the whole quiz. This will minimize latencies, but you must handle broken connections and reconnects manually.
  - Hybrid approach - choose [http](/questions/tagged/http) protocol with `Keep-alive` option
- in netty, avoid copying of byte arrays (`ChannelBuffer`/`ByteBuf` is pretty good at that) and creating too much garbage
- avoid blocking I/O operations in netty worker threads. Monitor how many worker threads are utilized, avoid queueing of netty events.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz, that's given me something to go on.